# Creating Team projects in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed VS 2017 and connected to TFS 2017 but can't seem to find the option to create new 'Team Project', in the previous versions of VS it was under 'File --> New--> Team Project'. Am I missing out on something? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I too experienced the same problem, apparently they changed the old behavior and hopefully they will update it to a more user-friendly experience in a future update.

Here is how to do it:

In your Team Explorer panel, click on *Home > Projects > New Team Project...*

Source: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project